# Sequencing collections in Scala

Tags: scala, for-loop, collections

This is my Scala code that returns all the class file names in a directory.

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
import java.io.File

def getFiles(directory:String) = {
    val files = ArrayBuffer[String]()
    val d = new File(directory)
    if (d.exists && d.isDirectory) {
        (for (i <- d.listFiles.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".class"))) // <--- 
            yield i.getName.replace(directory, "")).toList
    } else {
        List[String]()
    }
}
```

The `listFiles` method returns a collection of a File type class, and I had to use the `for` and `yield` to get a new collection of String. I think the code is ugly, and there might be better way to this pattern (generate a new type of collection from existing one) such as this code, but I have an error message with it.

```
d.listFiles.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".class")))
 .foreach(yield _.getName.replace(directory, "")).toList
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it the `.map(...)` you are looking for? =)

From what I see the right way to do it would be

```
d.listFiles.filter(...).map(_.getName.replace(directory, "")).toList
```